# pandas:count() how to select the value

Tags: pandas

how to get the value 7599 without all the line ?

```
app_train[app_train["target"]==1].count()

userkn_answernumcnt_cuishou                                          7599
userkn_answernumcnt_nonphonenoremark                                 7599
userkn_answernumcnt_noremark                                         7599
userkn_answernumcntdavg                                              7599
userkn_answertimescnt_bank                                           7599
userkn_answertimescnt_cuishou                                        7599
userkn_answertimescnt_nonphonenoremark                               7599
userkn_answertimescnt_noremark                                       7599
userkn_answertimescnt_xiaodai                                        7599
userkn_answertimescnt_xiaodaibank                                    7599
userkn_answertimescnt_zhongjie                                       7599
userkn_answertimescntdavg                                            7599
userkn_answertimescntrate_bank                                       7599
userkn_answertimescntrate_xiaodai                                    7599
userkn_answertimescntrate_xiaodaibank                                7599
userkn_answerxiaodaibanknumcnt                                       7599
userkn_answerxiaodaibanknumdmax                                      7599
```

Comment: Do you need `(app_train["target"]==1).sum()` ?

Comment: @jezraelneed only the value 7599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want count number of row by condition use `sum` of boolean mask:

```
(app_train["target"]==1).sum()
```